# Android Google Maps API v1 with Gradle

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle

I'm trying to build this super-old application using Google Maps v1, after migrating to gradle, but when I try to install it on the device, I cannot choose any device - all devices, in the 'Select Deployment Target' AS window, have in the right side :
"(minSDK(API 1, Google Inc.:Google APIs:15 preview) != deviceSdk(API 23))

This is how, part of my build.gradle file, looks like:

```
   android {
        compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:24"
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.mobile"
            minSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:15"
            targetSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:24"

            versionCode 77
            versionName "9.2.5"
        }  
. . . }
```

All entries, related to SDK from AndroidManifest.xml, have been removed.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
minSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:15"
targetSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:24"
```

with:

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 24
```

and see if you have better luck. I believe those need to be plain API levels; only `compileSdkVersion` gets the whole "Google APIs" bit.